# How does uplift lead to onlapping?

Tags: geology, seismic

I read in a paper that:

> Interpretation of 2-D seismic lines shows the lower to middle
> Patchawarra Formation onlapping onto paleostructural highs at
> approximately 270 Ma and again at 273 Ma, suggesting two periods of
> uplift.

Can someone please explain to me how uplift leads to onlapping?

Comment: Could you please add a link or reference to said article?

Comment: Apparently, the citation stems from https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2016TC004366. But it seems to be all in there with further links and reading ...